# Unable to boot from CD

Tags: boot, windows-xp, cd

I have just downloaded the Ubuntu file from the website and burned onto a cd. restarted my computer and got the computer to load from the CD drive but it sits on black screen for about 2 mins then says unable to boot, press any key to retry.

Apologies but I don't know if ou need any more info from me but if you do, please ask!

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Would you be able to try a USB drive instead, with startup disk creator (if you've already got a linux to work from) or pendrive linux (if working from Windows)? You might have better luck, and it's normally faster to work with than a CD.

Comment: Did you try the CD in a different machine, or another CD in the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to try intalling via `wubi`.

Load the image into virtual cd (like `Daemon Tools Lite` for Windows), and start `Wubi.exe`